# Do you bring anything "aus" or "vom" the supermarket?

Tags: preposition

When I stay at home and a friend of mine visits the town, how could I request him to buy something for me?

“aus” or “von”?

> Kannst du bitte vom Supermarkt Milch, Eier und Käse mitbringen?

Comment: Note that "vom" contains an article, but "aus" doesn't. So it must be "aus dem".

Comment: In your specific example "Aus (dem)" or "vom" are equally fine. As a native speaker I'd only use "von" to refer to a specific chain. Eg. "Kannst du bitte Spaghettisauce von Aldi mitbringen"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both are possible. With *aus*, you have the building in mind; with *von*, the institution (or in other cases, a person).

Consequently, you couldn’t say *aus dem Wochenmarkt* nor *aus dem Bäcker* (not a building; but *aus der Bäckerei* is possible).